# I can't handle populate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I think it's not populating categories couse when i try log 'category' in console i get
"ReferenceError: category is not defined". For me it is like in docs but as we see it's not. Is anyone can tell me what is wrong??

//model/Category.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 const CatSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
 mongoose.model("categories", CatSchema, "categories");
```

model/Story.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
     const StorySchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "categories"
    }

});
     mongoose.model("stories", StorySchema, "stories");
```

routes/stories.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Category = mongoose.model('categories');
const Story = mongoose.model('stories');
     router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    Story.find()
        .populate('category',  'title')
        .then(stories => {
            res.render('stories/add', {
                stories: stories
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: where are you trying to log 'category'? does query returns you `Story`s without populating `category`s? or it returns nothing at all? can you please post more code + some JSON that represents your schema from db?

Comment: res.render('stories/add', {
                stories: stories
            });
console.log(category); <---
        });
});

Comment: Yes it create object without category
///    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd3524d9d2bfc3a066ad538"
    },
    "title": "scs",
    "body": "<p>scss<\/p>\r\n",
    "__v": 0
}
////
res.render('stories/add', {
                stories: stories
            });

console.log(category); <--- i tried to log it here
        });
});

Comment: I can't even display categories in add.handlebars

Answer (score 1):

`Query.prototype.populate()` returns a `Query` object on which you need to run `.exec()`, try this:

```
Story.find({})
    .populate('category',  'title')
    .exec()
    .then(stories => {
        res.render('stories/add', {
            stories: stories
        });
});
```

Comment: Unforunately it change nothing

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with that how I want to use it. Code is working